# React js Active Menu Item with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to add a menu with an active styling by using useState in React js but for some reasons it only stays in active state, does not go back to inactive when you click on the other menu item. On the other hand, it works perfectly when I pass down my **active** state as props from Sidebar.js

**React version:** "react": "^17.0.2"
**Node version:** v16.0.0

Here is my code:

**SideLink.js**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const SideLink = ({ name, Icon}) => {
  const [active, setactive] = useState("Home")

  return (
    <li className="group" onClick={() => setactive(name)}>
      <a href={name.toLowerCase()} className="cursor-pointer block mb-2 pointer-events-none">
        <div className="inline-block">
          <div
            className={`
            flex items-center 
            group-hover:bg-blue-50 
            group-hover:text-red-500 
            rounded-full pl-2 py-3 pr-6
            ${active === name ? "text-red-400" : ""}
            `}
            >
            <Icon />
            <span className="ml-2 font-bold text-xl">{name}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  );
};

export default SideLink;
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import SideLink from "../../assets/components/SideLink";
import {
  BookmarksIcon,
  ExploreIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  ListsIcon,
  MessagesIcon,
  MoreIcon,
  NotificationsIcon,
  ProfileIcon,
} from "../../assets/icons/Icon";


const sideLinks = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    icon: HomeIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Explore",
    icon: ExploreIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Notifications",
    icon: NotificationsIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Messages",
    icon: MessagesIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Bookmarks",
    icon: BookmarksIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Lists",
    icon: ListsIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "Profile",
    icon: ProfileIcon,
  },
  {
    name: "More",
    icon: MoreIcon,
  },
];

const Sidebar = () => {

  return (
    <div className="w-72 flex flex-col justify-between px-2">
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            {sideLinks.map(({ name, icon }) => (
              <SideLink key={name} name={name} Icon={icon}/>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div>bottom</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Thank you!

Comment: care to explain why? Sorry, just trying to understand the logic behind.. Thanks!~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that in your example each `SideLink` maintain their own independent state. When one of those call its own `setactive`, it doesn't have any effect on any other.

What I think you really want is one piece of state that live in a central location, the parent component, `Sidebar`, and forward to `SideLink` that value and the means to change that it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! Now, I fully understand the logic behind that approach.